# Datevalue can't read december month

Tags: vba, excel

I work on a macro vba which manipulate different dates.
I have an incomprehensive error with Decembre. For exemple

```
DateValue("11-NOV-14")
```

return : 11/11/2014

```
DateValue("11-DEC-14")
```

return an error type '13'

I already try to put the string into a var and pass it to DateValue but same results.

Maybe i can get around this problem but i want to know why i have this mystic error.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are those values really hard coded in your code and returning an error?  or are they really variables and you have entered them as text in your question?  The reason I ask is that if I run the below code, it works fine and outputs 11/12/2014
`Sub test()
MsgBox DateValue("11-DEC-14")
End Sub`

Comment: Hi Mark, yes it's hard coded

Comment: I admit to clutching at straws a little here, but as DateValue can be influenced by your systems Date settings, can you confirm what language and regional settings you have for date in Windows?

Comment: It's on my profesionnal computer so settings acces are restricted.
But i guess it's European format (French). Anyway "DD-MMM-AA" is a worldwide format, i suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your is a system-dependent problem. The month of November passes well because, in French, November = Novembre so "11-NOV-14" is equal to the English version.

However, "Décembre" is different because it has an accent on the second letter. In fact, on a French system, this will be ok:

```
a = DateValue("11-DéC-14")
```

while this will be not:

```
a = DateValue("11-DEC-14")
```

To avoid this problem and make the code "language-independent" (without asking the user to change the date formatting from the Control Panel), I think you should add a function that translate dates from string to date values:

```
Function MyDateValue(ByVal myDate As String) As Date
    myDay = Left(myDate,2)
    myMonth = Right(Left(myDate,6),3)
    Select Case myMonth
        Case "JAN":
            myMonth = 1
        'etc.
    End Select
    myYear = Right(myDate,2)
    MyDateValue = DateSerial(myYear,myMonth,myDay)
End Function
```

So, you will be able to use `myDateValue` rather than `DateValue` and will make sure that it will work with your input data whatever will be the system language.